# lvextend New size matches existing size

Tags: centos, partition, centos8

I added 500GBs of space to a virtual disk that I am trying to add to a volume group in Centos 8.

When I run

```
lvextend -An -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/cl_elk/root
```

I get

```
  New size (9692 extents) matches existing size (9692 extents).
```

After adding the disk space I did cfdisk and assigned the space to the partition that the LVM is using which seems to all have gone smoothly.

```
lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0   560G  0 disk 
├─sda1            8:1    0   600M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2            8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3            8:3    0 558.4G  0 part 
  ├─cl_elk-root 253:0    0  37.9G  0 lvm  /
  ├─cl_elk-swap 253:1    0   2.1G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─cl_elk-home 253:2    0  18.5G  0 lvm  /home
sr0              11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

From my understanding (and the many articles that I read which are all now confusing me) my next step should be to extend with lvextend.

```
vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               cl_elk
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               3
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               58.41 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              14953
  Alloc PE / Size       14953 / 58.41 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               GzXr0X-AZRj-LNZz-a2ma-JhPy-Oyxe-WPYMje


df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    3.9G   99M  3.8G   3% /run
tmpfs                    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/cl_elk-root   38G   34G  4.1G  90% /
/dev/mapper/cl_elk-home   19G  451M   19G   3% /home
/dev/sda2                976M  239M  671M  27% /boot
/dev/sda1                599M  6.8M  593M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                    781M  1.2M  780M   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                    781M  4.0K  781M   1% /run/user/1000
```

I know this should be a simple fix but in all my reading I haven't found a solution.

How can I add my extra space to my root logical volume?

Answer (score 2):

In keeping with my track record of finding my answer as soon as I post the question I found that

```
pvresize /dev/sda3
```

was my answer.  Strangely I know I had tried that previously but I didn't document what message I was getting for it so I don't know what about it failed.